# Update statement on PostgreSQL not using primary key index to update

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure on PostgreSQL like this:

```
create or replace procedure new_emp_sp (f_name varchar, l_name varchar, age integer, threshold integer, dept varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    new_emp_count integer;
begin
    INSERT INTO employees (id, first_name, last_name, age)
        VALUES (nextval('emp_id_seq'), 
                random_string(10),
                random_string(20),
                age);
    select count(*) into new_emp_count from employees where age > threshold;
    update dept_employees set emp_count = new_emp_count where id = dept;
end; $$
```

I have enabled `auto_explain` module and set `log_min_duration` to 0 so that it logs everything.

I have an issue with the update statement in the procedure. From the `auto_explain` logs I see that it is not using the primary key index to update the table:

```
->  Seq Scan on dept_employees  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((id)::text = 'ABC'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3
```

This worked as expected **until a couple of hours ago** and I used to get a log like this:

```
->  Index Scan using dept_employees_pkey on dept_employees  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((id)::text = 'ABC'::text)
```

Without the procedure, if I run the statement standalone like this:

```
explain analyze update dept_employees set emp_count = 123 where id = 'ABC';
```

The statement correctly uses the primary key index:

```
Update on dept_employees  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.049..0.049 rows=0 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using dept_employees_pkey on dept_employees  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((id)::text = 'ABC'::text)
```

I can't figure out what has gone wrong especially because it worked perfectly just a couple of hours ago.

Comment: I don’t understand the question, do you actually have a problem? You complain about the query plan, but does the changed plan have a problem or is it just different?

Comment: The Seq Scan is reported on a table with just 4 rows. I doubt using an index scan would make things any faster on such a tiny table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but it uses the index when I run the query manually? By manually I mean without calling the stored procedure

Comment: @FrankHeikens basically I want to know this: when I run stored procedure, the update query does not use the index but when I run the SAME query manually, the index is used.

Comment: There can be a difference in planning when using stored procedures/functions. In your case you're updating an almost empty table within a fraction of a millisecond no matter what query plan is used.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html

Comment: Best guess is that in the interval `autovacuum` ran and updated the statistics for the table and the planner no longer sees a need to use the index. For this small a table you are better off without the overhead of an index lookup anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is faster to scan N rows sequentially than to scan N rows using an index. So for small tables Postgres may decide that a sequence scan is faster than an index scan.

[PL/pgSQL can cache prepared statements and execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING), so you're probably getting a cached execution plan from when the table was smaller.